# How can I move the vertical line in an axes by a slider within a MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, line, move

I want to change the vertical line position by a slider. The codes as follows.

```
function slider_wf_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider_wf (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider
global FLAG_DATA_LOADED;
if FLAG_DATA_LOADED == 1
    slider_value = int32(get(hObject,'Value'));
    set(handles.text_cur_frame_num, 'String',num2str(slider_value));

    axes(handles.axes_waveform);
    h = vline(slider_value/20, 'r-');
end
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

However, when I moved the slider, the previous lines still existed. How to solve this problem?

[image: Image sample]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean to resize the time axis? I didn't understand what you meant by "previous lines"

Comment: If I move the slider for the first time, there is a red vertical line; but if I move the slider again, the first line did not disappear and the second line showed up. I hope there is only one line followed by where I move the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a function `vline`, but I assume that it returns the handle to a `Line`. You have to either delete the old line and draw a new one or manipulate the position of the already existing line. In both cases, you have to store the handle somewhere. In GUIDE, the `handles` struct is used for that.

This is the solution deleting the old `Line`:

```
if isfield(handles, 'myvline') % on the first run, no handle is available
    delete(handles.myvline);
end
handles.myvline = vline(slider_value/20, 'r-');

% ...

guidata(hObject, handles); % important, used to update the handles struct
```

Second attempt by manipulating the existing `Line`

```
if isfield(handles, 'myvline') % on the first run, no handle is available
    handles.myvline.XData(:) = slider_value/20;
else
    handles.myvline = vline(slider_value/20, 'r-');
end

% ...

guidata(hObject, handles); % important, used to update the handles struct
```

Comment: Your try-catch approach is not working. I think it's better checking if field exists: `if isfield(handles, 'myvline')` ...

Comment: Only in the second case, but you are right! I have updated the answer.